# Aligning content in css with floats not aligning

Tags: html, css, css-float, alignment

I think I am having an issue with my floats, they are not aligning correctly and I feel like it has to do with the way I have my boxes setup. I have tried changing the alignment with margin-left and right but am not getting the desired look, I would like all of it to lineup. Here is the html and css.

HTML

```
<div id="service1">
    <center>
    <h1>Savings <br />Strategies</h1>
    <img src="images/eg1.png" class="alignleft" height="150" width="200" alt="" />
    </center>
</div>

<div id="service2">
    <center>
    <h1>Vendor <br />Management</h1>
    <img src="images/eg2.png" class="alignleft" height="150" width="200" alt="" />
    </center>
</div>

<div id="service3">
    <center>
    <h1>Environmental<br /> Stewardship</h1>
    <img src="images/eg3.png" class="alignleft" height="150" width="200" alt="" />
    </center>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#service1 {
float:left;
width:360px;
height:280px;
padding:15px;
}

#service2 {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:360px;
height:280px;
padding:15px;
}

#service3 {
float:right;
width:360px;
height:280px;
padding 15px; 
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not try displaying each div as an inline-block. Remove all the floats and margins as well.

> div { display: inline-block; }

Answer (score 1):

You could set `display` to `inline` and remove all the margins:
http://jsfiddle.net/ABVJd/2/
Result: http://jsfiddle.net/ABVJd/2/embedded/result

Either that,, or you could remove all margins and floats and add inline-block, as suggested:
http://jsfiddle.net/ABVJd/3/
Result:[http://jsfiddle.net/ABVJd/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/ABVJd/3/embedded/result)